# how can upload video to server use php and mysql?

Tags: android, video, android-recyclerview, okhttp

how can upload a video to a PHP server used MySQL?

now, I can upload Image to the server, but how can add upload video function?

this is my code

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/status_edit"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_proper"/>

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/status_edit"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_proper"/>
```

and I tried to add this code

```
private void selectVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO);
    }


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode== IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
            Uri path = data.getData();

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),path);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(requestCode== VIDEO && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){

        }
    }
```

if I choose the video, how can set it into the VideoView? And when I upload the data, I need to what?

in the image, I need to convertToString to bitmap. So in the video, may I convert?

```
private void uploadImage(){
        String userID = getID;
        String image = convertToString();
        String imageName = statusEdit.getText().toString();
        String sp2 = sp.getText().toString();
        String tag = tags.getText().toString();
```

and can I setting the video size or time less than 30 seconds?

Comment: If you can upload an image file in the right way (not messsing around with bitmaps and such) then you can upload any file. But you do not show any upload code. `String image = convertToString();` Well that looks the wrong way. But... maybe.. And we have no idea what you convert to string. Is the result in base64?

Comment: @blackapps yes, it's base64 format.